# How do I repair the solder of this component?

Tags: soldering

The chip is a chip that is surface mounted to the main PCB.
This solder gave out and separated from the PCB as shown below.

I'm not very well skilled in soldering, but it seems a bit too fine for a normal soldering iron. Should I use solder paste and a heat gun? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Small tip solder iron would be my first pick but you can probably do it with paste and heat gun too.

Comment: That looks like 2mm spacing, maybe even standard 0.1inch. I'd say that should be doable with any electronics soldering iron (maybe not the bigger ones for large wiring).

Comment: Your photo contains far too much irrelevant stuff, take a picture of the line of pads on the main PCB with the daughter board just below nearby so people can get a better look at the important area. After adequate cleanup it surely won't be a problem for a normal electronics soldering iron even with a relatively large tip. If the boards have adequate solder mask, you shouldn't have any trouble at all.

Comment: Winny might be skilled enough to use a heat gun on something he wants to use afterwards, I only use one for destructive disassembly! That pad pitch is fine for an ordinary soldering iron.

Comment: It looks slightly lame design for that relatively long daughter board to be held only by the solder joints. Any sort of vibration and it's only a matter of time before it's off again. Secure it in a few places with hot melt.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this can be answered objectively. You already know the options, and whichever is better depends solely on your skill with it.

Comment: That is absolutely no problem to hand solder.  Use a soldering iron with a small point.  Don't use a soldering gun, and don't use a 150Watt iron with a half inch wide tip. Had to do that once to fix my father in laws TV. I got it done with that huge (cherry red glowing iron) but I don't recommend doing that if you can avoid it.

Comment: To me it looks like you ripped off the pads as well, making it impossible to solder again. But this is hard to judge given the quality of images supplied.

Comment: The pads look fine.  There's a ridge across all the pads where it was soldered.

Comment: The link goes to an album, my question was edited to show only the one picture. But you can get a better look in the album. @replete

Comment: I've also discovered that later versions of this remote do have hot melt to hold this daughter board in place. I do worry about the pads on the main PCB though, it looks like they're ripped off.

Comment: It is **extremely** lame to design a module with castellations along one edge only. If they are the only mechanical support, they must be used on at least two opposing edges. This module was designed by an amateur, not a professional. And it isn't the solder that failed -- the copper pads have been ripped off the board altogether. You can even see the bare copper ends of the torn traces that run underneath the module. The PCB is toast -- not economically repairable. Just toss it and get a new one, and be sure to secure the new module with glue *before* you break it!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a normal soldering iron (preferably temperature controlled) and [liquid solder flux](https://www.jaycar.co.nz/solder-flux-pen-12ml/p/NS3036). Apply flux liberally, then put a little solder on the iron tip and rake it down the pins on an angle to heat up several pins at once (or use a 3mm spade tip like I do).

The flux should prevent solder from bridging the pins. If a solder bridge does occur then use [desoldering braid](https://www.jaycar.co.nz/2-0mm-goot-desolder-braid/p/NS3027) to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use solder iron, then here is an alternate method:

1. Apply liquid flux on the pads of the IC.
2. Apply some solder on the pads and then place the IC carefully in place, and
3. Use the hot air blower/heat gun to secure it firmly in place.

PS: Where your IC pads are, I can see some capacitors and other components. So, you'll have to use your heat gun very carefully.

I'd personally prefer to solder this IC than relying on heat gun to do the job. If the heat gun displaces the caps while placing your IC correctly, re-placing those caps would be much tougher later.

Answer (score 0):

I would go at it like this.

1. Use solder wick to clean the pads of both boards. You want the pads of both to be clean and smooth.
2. Use a soldering iron with a fine tip, and 0.5 mm solder.  It can be done with thicker solder, but I use 0.5mm for just about everything.
3. Heat one pad one the main board with the iron, and melt a bit of solder onto the pad.
4. Put the smaller module in place and line it up properly.
5. Melt the solder on the one tinned pad, and push the smaller board down on the larger one so that they are flat on one another.
6. Remove the iron and let the pad cool.
7. Check alignmeny.  If crooked, reheat and adjust.
8. Solder all of the pads, including the first one.  It won't be perfect because of the reheating, so it must be redone.